# Segmentation Error in strcmp() function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, strcmp

The following code is to sort a linked list after creating it. The sorting algorithm used is Bubble Sort. Somehow the code raises a Segmentation Fault in the strcmp() function.

PS: I also wrote another version where instead of counting the number of nodes, I used pointers to run the loop for sorting. There too a Segmentation Fault was raised. This time in the "condition checking" of the loop

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct link_list  
{    
       char value[20];  
       struct link_list *next;  
};  

int main()  
{  
    struct link_list *head=NULL;  
    int i,j,count=0;  
    char input[20];  
    char ch;  
    struct link_list *temp=NULL,*temp2=NULL,*temp3=NULL,*temp4=NULL;  
    do  /* Creating a link list*/  
    {  
        cout<<"Enter the string you want to insert";  
        cin>>input;
        count++;  
        cout<<"Do you want to continue entering?";  
        cin>>ch;

       if  (head==NULL)
       {
           head=new link_list;
           strcpy(head->value,input);
           head->next=NULL;
           continue;
       }
       for (temp=head;temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next);
       temp2=new link_list;
       temp->next=temp2;
       strcpy(temp2->value,input);
       temp2->next=NULL;
    }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');

   /*Printing the link list*/

   for (temp=head;temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next)
   {
       cout<<temp->value<<"\n";
   }
   cout<<temp->value<<"\n";
   temp=head;
   temp2=head;

/*Using Bubble Sort to sort the list in ascending order*/

   for (i=1;i<count-1;i++)
   {
       if  (i==1)
           temp=head;
       else
           temp=temp->next;
       for (j=0;j<count-i;j++)
       {
           if  (j==0)
               temp4=head;
           else
               temp4=temp4->next;
           temp2=temp4;
           /*Comparing two subsequent nodes and swapping pointers if necessary*/
           if  (strcmp(temp2->value,temp2->next->value)>0)/*<----ERROR in some cases*/
           {
               /*Case where head node needs to adjusted, 2 nodes present in the list*/
               if  (temp2==head && temp2->next->next==NULL)
               {
                   cout<<"Special1\n";
                   head=temp->next;
                   temp2->next->next=temp;
                   temp2->next=NULL;
               }
               /*Case where head node needs to be adjusted*/
               else if (temp2==head)
               {
                    cout<<"Special2\n";
                    head=temp2->next;
                    temp2->next=head->next;
                    head->next=temp2;
               }
               /*Rest of the cases*/
               else
               {
                   cout<<"Normal1\n";
                   temp3->next=temp2->next;
                   temp2->next=temp3->next->next;
                   temp3->next->next=temp2;
                   cout<<"Normal2\n";
               }
           }
           temp3=temp4;
       }
    }

    for (temp=head;temp->next!=NULL;temp=temp->next)
    {
       cout<<temp->value<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<temp->value;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`)? I guess that in your `strcmp` call `temp2->next` is sometimes `NULL` hence a `SIGSEGV`

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 possibilities:

- `temp2` is invalid (or NULL)
- `temp2->next` is invalid (or NULL)

My guess is the second bullet.

Comment: I edited the code omitting the algorithm using the number of nodes and used a different algorithm. Please refer to the question in the given link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707773/segmentation-fault-in-loops-condition)