# Segmentation Fault in Loop's Condition

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The following code is to sort a linked list after creating it. The sorting algorithm used is somewhat similar to Bubble Sort. I am checking the two consecutive nodes and swapping them if necessary. I used the debugger which told me that the fault is raised while condition checking for the loops which are used while sorting.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct link_list
{
       char value[20];
       struct link_list *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct link_list *head=NULL;
    int i,j;
    char input[20];
    char ch;
    struct link_list *loop_var,*temp2,*prev_node,*temp4=NULL;
    temp3=NULL;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter the string you want to insert";
        cin>>input;

        cout<<"\nDo you want to continue entering?";
        cin>>ch;

        if  (head==NULL)
        {
            head=new link_list;
            strcpy(head->value,input);
            head->next=NULL;
            continue;
        }
        for (loop_var=head;loop_var->next!=NULL;loop_var=loop_var->next);
        temp2=new link_list;
        loop_var->next=temp2;
        strcpy(temp2->value,input);
        temp2->next=NULL;
    }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');

    for (loop_var=head;loop_var->next!=NULL;loop_var=loop_var->next)
    {
        cout<<loop_var->value<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<loop_var->value<<"\n";

    char arr[20];

    for (loop_var=head;loop_var->next!=NULL;loop_var=loop_var->next)
    {
        cout<<"\nLoop1";
        for (temp4=head;temp4->next!=NULL;temp4=temp4->next)
        {
            cout<<"\nLoop2";
            temp2=temp4;
            if  (strcmp(temp2->value,temp2->next->value)>0)
            {
                cout<<"\nSwap Enter";

                if  (temp2==head && temp2->next->next==NULL)
                {
                    cout<<"\nSpecial1";
                    temp2->next->next=temp;
                    temp2->next=NULL;
                }
                else if (temp2==head)
                {
                     cout<<"\nSpecial2";
                     head=temp2->next;
                     temp2->next=head->next;
                     head->next=temp2;
                }
                else if (temp2->next->next==NULL)
                {
                     cout<<"\nSpecial3";
                     prev_node->next=temp2->next;
                     prev_node->next->next=temp2;
                     temp2->next=NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"\nNormal1";
                    prev_node->next=temp2->next;
                    temp2->next=prev_node->next->next;
                    prev_node->next->next=temp2;
                    cout<<"\nNormal2";
                }
            }
            prev_node=temp4; 
            cout<<"\nLoop2PreExit";
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"\nLoop2Exit";
        }
        cout<<"\nLoop1Exit";
    }
    for (loop_var=head;loop_var->next!=NULL;loop_var=loop_var->next)
    {
        cout<<loop_var->value<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<loop_var->value;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Which loop ? there are like 10 here.

Comment: The one with "Loop1" and "Loop2" printed inside it.

Comment: Can you post what input you are using? I tried with c, b, a and it didn't crash (didn't sort correctly either mind you).

Comment: Well it crashes when I input, "c", "b" and "a". However my test input is "z", "c", "b", "a".

Comment: I can see that temp3 is initialized to NULL, and then you do `temp3->next = temp2->next`. To me the code is confused, I'm not sure it can be rescued.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: @RobertoWilko the purpose of the loop is to set `temp` to point to the last item in the list.

Comment: First things first, you can easily notice that temp3 will never be executed the first time Loop2 is executed, and if it is executed the 2nd time, I initialize it to temp4.

Comment: @RobertoWilko because the only way to get to the end of the list is to write a loop? I'm not sure I understand your question. This part of the code is working correctly at least.

Comment: @RobertoWilko, what jahhaj said. As I mentioned I first create the link list. The loop gets me to the last node and there I add the current string as a new node.

Comment: @jahhaj, temp3 is pointing to the node, previous to the node pointed by temp2. So temp3 is initialized only after Loop2 is executed the first time. However we can see that the section of the code using temp3 will never be executed the first time loop2 is executed as temp2==head.

Comment: @user1560644 - OK I can see that now, still seems very confused to me though, code shouldn't be that hard to understand. You've worked out the immediate cause of your error? At the top of loop2 you do `temp2=temp2->next`, after doing that `temp2` may be NULL, but the next thing is the condition test `temp2->next == NULL` which will crash if `temp2` is NULL. But I can't help you with the fix for that as the logic you're trying to implement is too complex.

Comment: `else if (temp2==head) {
....
}` you should add an extra line at the end `temp2=head`; otherwise `temp2` will point one node past.

Comment: @jahhaj, I have to disagree with you again. temp2 should never be NULL. Because if it were NULL, the loop wouldn't have gone for this iteration and would have ended the previous time. Tell me if I am not making myself clear enough.

Comment: Also, i see your logic is not correct in this part: `else if (temp2->next->next==NULL) {.......}`. I assume that you are using `temp3` as a reference of `temp2`'s previous node. But it isn't working. I see `temp3` and `temp2` is pointing at the same node.

Comment: @user1560644 All that I can say is that when I debugged it temp2 was NULL at this point and that is why it crashed. Clearly there's some difference between what you think the code does and what it actually does. This is normal, it's just a matter of figuring it out.

Comment: @user1560644 Why aren't you using doubly linked list? You don't need to maintain so much messy `temp` then. Sorting a single linked list is not a very good idea as you can't access the previous node directly.

Comment: @Rafi, I understood the issue you referred to, and so I changed the Loop2's variable from temp2 to temp4 and the next statement from temp4=temp2 to temp2=temp4. That should have done the trick. Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: @user1560644 I know it's not immediately relevant but Rafi's point is a good one, it would be an improvement if you named your variables after their purpose, instead of just temp, temp2 temp3, temp4. This would help others understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree with your point completely. I will try to rename as my variables as I can.

Comment: Thanks guys, the verdict's in...I'm a du-mass! It makes too much sense now!

Comment: @Rafi, I edited the code, that should take care of the issue of temp3 and temp2 pointing to the same node.

Comment: you know that C and C++ are two different languages, right? If you're serious about learning C++, get a quality C++ book and read it. You'll save a lot of time doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    temp2->next->next=temp;
```

"temp" is not defined anywhere...  if your compiler filled in that hole for you, then this is what is causing your loop's condition to segfault.

Also, naming every other variable "temp#" is an easy way to have mistakes like this.